# Mojave Html Mail Dark Mode: Prevent certain elements from being altered

Tags: html, email, macos-mojave, macos-darkmode, macos-mail-app

Mail in Mac OS Mojave alters the colors of html emails, (it appears in cases when no images are present [1](https://www.maildesigner365.com/the-secret-to-building-dark-mode-email-newsletters-for-macos-mojave-mail/) and dark mode is enabled)

This is all fine, except when an email also contains a logo as svg image. Mail now takes the svg image and "inverts" all colors. Intended behaviour would be that Mail inverts all colors of the mail excluding the logo. Is there any known way to instruct mail to not modify the colors of a single element (probably via css or an element)?